# How to disable access to Sitemap.xml file outside the production server in mvc4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, mvcsitemapprovider

I am trying to disable access to Sitemap.xml file outside the production environment. currently if user types http://localhost:62777/sitemap.xml it is accessible but i want to restrict it. currently i tried as below but no luck

```
<location path="sitemap.xml">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

is there any other way to disable it from outside the production environment? Thanks in advance. 
i tried as below also but not working

```
<httpHandlers>

    <add path="sitemap.xml" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler" name="xml (integrated)" preCondition="integratedMode" />
  </httpHandlers>
```

Comment: http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/filteringrules/filteringrule/appliesto

Comment: thanks i added .xml in iis request handlers. where can i mark as answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why in the world do you want to "restrict" it? `/sitemap.xml` needs to be publicly available or the search engines (which is what it is for) won't read it. See the [protocol definition on Sitemaps.org](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html).

That said, if you don't want to use it for some reason (such as rolling your own sitemap solution or if your site is not Internet facing), you can [disable it](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Configuring-MvcSiteMapProvider#mvcsitemapprovider_enablesitemapsxml).

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_EnableSitemapsXml" value="false"/>
</appSettings>
```

Comment: yes this worked perfectly. I enabed it and put above line of code.

Answer (score 0):

you can add in IIS [Please see here](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/filteringrules/filteringrule/appliesto)